# How to debug in zend studio

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

I am using zend studio built on eclipse.

Now the problem is when I make zend framework project and start debugging when I click on controller than it gets terminated.  I have to right click on index.php and than debug as script.

Now I want like when I fill form in web browser and want to keep breakpoint in the controller. But I'm not able to do this...

Comment: There is not enough information. Really hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Download the FireFox Debugger Toolbar for Zend Studio, you can debug right from the browser which allows you to test live input, including the data you enter on forms. It will recognize your breakpoints in the Controller.

You'll need to provide more information if this doesn't help you.